# SQL server : resolving group membership

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have a table as follows (Table Groups):

```
Name      Members

Group1    Toto;Tata;Group2
Group2    Group3;Titi
Group3    Tutu
```

My goal is resolving group membership:

```
Name      Members

Group1    Toto;Tata;Titi;Tutu
Group2    Tutu;Titi
Group3    Tutu
```

To do this, I created a function that:

- separates users to have one line per username
- resolves group membership (only once)

I use sql server 2017.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetMembers ( @strGroup VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(  
  SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT (
      SELECT members
      FROM [groups]
      WHERE [name] LIKE @strGroup
  ), ';' 
)
```

So, when I call `SELECT * FROM dbo.GetMembers ('Group1')`, the result is:

```
value

Toto
Tata
Group3
Titi
```

I would like to generalize this query to resolve all group memberships. How to proceed in sql with sql server?

Comment: You can use a recursive CTE for this, but it may turn out to be very inefficient indeed when operating on data that needs to be continuously `STRING_SPLIT`, at which point you should seriously consider maintaining a properly normalized version of this data instead. Rewriting clients only hurts once (and you can use stored procedures to lessen the pain); dragging this table design around will hurt forever. As a bonus, if you do redesign dedicated types like `hierarchyid` become an option (which may or may not be a good fit for your scenario, but it's nice to have the option).

Comment: I will try to redesign by adding a `users_groups` table (`userid`, `groupid`). I am curious to see how to solve this problem with CTE, so I keep the question.